# navbar toogle button is not working after scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

so i have this navbar which is working fine. when i click the toogle icon it scrolls but then after i can't see the toogle icon. if i try to click the toogle icon it's not working. i  mean it  dose not scroll back. i don't know what is going wrong. how do i solve the Problem ? below is the working example of my code.

**Working Sample**

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

/* h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 46%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-family: "Playfair Display";
    font-weight: lighter;
} */
/* 
body{
    background: #101010;
} */
.toggle-btn {
    position: fixed;
    margin: 1.4em;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 40px;
    height: 12px;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

span.one {
    position: fixed;
    width: 40px;
    height: 2px;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    margin-right: 60px;
}

span.two {
    position: fixed;
    width: 40px;
    height: 2px;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-right: 60px;
}

.menu {
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    background:#000000;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    top: -200%;
}

.data {
    padding: 8em 0 0 2em;
    text-align: left;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

li:first-child {
    color: grey;
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-size: 24px;
}

li:not(:first-child) {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 42px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #cccccc;
    font-family: Poppins;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">


 <!-- navigation animation -->

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',  filename='dist/css/nav.css') }}">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>


 <!-- gallery css -->


 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/baguettebox.js/1.10.0/baguetteBox.min.css"/>
 <!-- google fonts -->

 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400|Roboto+Mono:300i,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

 <!-- gsap -->
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

 <!-- jquery -->

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

 <!-- parllax javascript -->
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-parallax-js@5.2.0/dist/simpleParallax.min.js"></script>

 <!-- bootstrap CDN -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='dist/css/custom.css') }}">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='node_modules/sal.js/dist/sal.css') }}">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='dist/css/grid-gallery.css') }}">
 <!-- font awesome -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">
 <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a766f28a10.js"></script>
 <title>AW Zone / {{title}}</title>
 <style>
  body {
   font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
   font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   width: 100%;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <!-- new navigation is here -->
 <div class="toggle-btn">
  <span class="one"></span>
  <span class="two"></span>
   </div>

   <div class="menu">
  <div class="data">
    <ul>
      <li>Navigation</li>
      <li ><a href="{{ url_for('index') }}" style="color: #ffffff;text-decoration: none;">Home</a></li>
      <li ><a href="{{ url_for('gallery') }}" style="color: #ffffff;text-decoration: none;">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="{{ url_for('about') }}" style="color: #ffffff;text-decoration: none;">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="{{ url_for('contact') }}" style="color: #ffffff;text-decoration: none;">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   </div>
 <!-- navbar ends here -->
  
  
  <!-- bootstrap 4 JAVASCRIPT  -->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!-- greensock -->
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.1.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="{{  url_for('static', filename='node_modules/sal.js/dist/sal.js') }}"></script>




  <!-- script for gallery animation -->
<script type="text/javascript">

    var t1 = new TimelineMax({paused: true});

    t1.to(".one", 0.8, {
         y: 6,
         rotation: 45,
         opacity:1,
         ease: Expo.easeInOut
    });
    t1.to(".two", 0.8, {
         y: -6,
         opacity: 1,
         rotation: -45,
         ease: Expo.easeInOut,
         delay: -0.8
    });

    t1.to(".menu", 2, {
         top: "0%",
         ease: Expo.easeInOut,
         delay: -2
    });

    t1.staggerFrom(".menu ul li", 2, {x: -200, opacity: 0, ease:Expo.easeOut}, 0.3);

    t1.reverse();
    $(document).on("click", ".toggle-btn", function() {
         t1.reversed(!t1.reversed());
    });
  
 </script>
 <!-- gallery effects -->

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/baguettebox.js/1.10.0/baguetteBox.min.js"></script>


 <!-- script for gallery animation -->
 <script>
  baguetteBox.run('.grid-gallery', { animation: 'slideIn'});
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have incremented z-index value. Now you can close the navbar upon clicking the side icon. I have also changed background color of the snackbar upon clicking on it in order to distinguish in between colors.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}


/* h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 46%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-family: "Playfair Display";
    font-weight: lighter;
} */


/* 
body{
    background: #101010;
} */

.toggle-btn {
  position: fixed;
  margin: 1.4em;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 40px;
  height: 12px;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}

span.one {
  position: fixed;
  width: 40px;
  height: 2px;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  margin-right: 60px;
}

span.two {
  position: fixed;
  width: 40px;
  height: 2px;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-right: 60px;
}

.menu {
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  background: #000000;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  top: -200%;
}

.data {
  padding: 8em 0 0 2em;
  text-align: left;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li:first-child {
  color: grey;
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-size: 24px;
}

li:not(:first-child) {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 42px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #cccccc;
  font-family: Poppins;
}

.colorchange {
  background: white !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">


  <!-- navigation animation -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',  filename='dist/css/nav.css') }}">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>


  <!-- gallery css -->


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/baguettebox.js/1.10.0/baguetteBox.min.css" />
  <!-- google fonts -->

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400|Roboto+Mono:300i,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- gsap -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

  <!-- jquery -->

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

  <!-- parllax javascript -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-parallax-js@5.2.0/dist/simpleParallax.min.js"></script>

  <!-- bootstrap CDN -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='dist/css/custom.css') }}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='node_modules/sal.js/dist/sal.css') }}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='dist/css/grid-gallery.css') }}">
  <!-- font awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a766f28a10.js"></script>
  <title>AW Zone / {{title}}</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
      font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- new navigation is here -->
  <div class="toggle-btn">
    <span class="one"></span>
    <span class="two"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="menu">
    <div class="data">
      <ul>
        <li>Navigation</li>
        <li><a href="{{ url_for('index') }}" style="color: #ffffff;text-decoration: none;">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ url_for('gallery') }}" style="color: #ffffff;text-decoration: none;">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ url_for('about') }}" style="color: #ffffff;text-decoration: none;">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ url_for('contact') }}" style="color: #ffffff;text-decoration: none;">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- navbar ends here -->


  <!-- bootstrap 4 JAVASCRIPT  -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- greensock -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.1.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="{{  url_for('static', filename='node_modules/sal.js/dist/sal.js') }}"></script>




  <!-- script for gallery animation -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var t1 = new TimelineMax({
      paused: true
    });

    t1.to(".one", 0.8, {
      y: 6,
      rotation: 45,
      opacity: 1,
      ease: Expo.easeInOut
    });
    t1.to(".two", 0.8, {
      y: -6,
      opacity: 1,
      rotation: -45,
      ease: Expo.easeInOut,
      delay: -0.8
    });

    t1.to(".menu", 2, {
      top: "0%",
      ease: Expo.easeInOut,
      delay: -2
    });

    t1.staggerFrom(".menu ul li", 2, {
      x: -200,
      opacity: 0,
      ease: Expo.easeOut
    }, 0.3);

    t1.reverse();
    $(document).on("click", ".toggle-btn", function() {
      t1.reversed(!t1.reversed());
      $("span.one").toggleClass("colorchange");
      $("span.two").toggleClass("colorchange");
    });
  </script>
  <!-- gallery effects -->

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/baguettebox.js/1.10.0/baguetteBox.min.js"></script>


  <!-- script for gallery animation -->
  <script>
    baguetteBox.run('.grid-gallery', {
      animation: 'slideIn'
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response. worked for me, accepted your answer!